# Python init and Objects

Tags: python

I have this issue. I wouldn't know if there is any short-cut to it but I would love a short-cut though.

Say I have this class

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<a(%s', '%s')>" % (self.x, self.y)

    def b(self):
        print('First Name:', self.x, '\nLast Name:', self.y)


user = a('Ade', 'Shola')
```

Assuming there is only the first name,

```
user = a('Ade')
```

Can't I still run the script with some 'tweaks'?

Comment: This belongs on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5):

Just set a null default value for the last parameter:

```
def __init__(self, x, y=None):
```

You'll need to check for `y is None` in a lot of your logic.

Comment: This is a good answer. I'd just add that if there's a default value for the y parameter when it isn't supplied you can do a: y = 'Doe', for instance. In this case it might make sense to put y = '', then it doesn't break your code and just leaves the missing argument blank when it is inserted into strings for display.

Comment: I edited your post to follow pep8 style and fix a bug -- use `is None` instead of `== None`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this so set value of any field that you want...

```
>>> class a(object):
    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[a(%s', '%s')]" % (self.x, self.y)

    def b(self):
        print('First Name:', self.x, '\nLast Name:', self.y)

>>> user=a('nsn')
>>> user
[a (nsn', 'None')[
>>> user=a(x='xyx')
>>> user
[a(xyx', 'None')]
>>> user=a(y='abc')
>>> user
[a(None', 'abc')]
>>>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For the future, you don't have to try so hard to get your formatting right. Just hilight the code and click the `{}` button. Or indent anything that's code by 4 spaces.